# Positioning of checkboxes

Tags: html, css, forms

I would like the "Side 1" and "Side 4" checkbox to be positioned differently. I would I know this would be done in CSS I just can't seem to make it work myself. Thanks in advance

[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F5Eh.png)

[What I would like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osVBp.png)

```html
<form class="calculator">
                    <label for="base_width">Base Width (m)</label>
                    <input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="20" step="1" id="base_width" name="base_width">
            
                    <label for="base_length">Base Length (m)</label>
                    <input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="20" sstep="1" id="base_length" name="base_length">
            
                    <label for="wall">Wall Type</label>
                        <select name="walltype" id="walltype">
                            <option value="40">Inflated</option>
                            <option value="25">Netted</option>
                        </select>
                    
                    <div>
                       <p> Please choose where you want the walls placed</p>
                        <label for="wall_side1">Side 1</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="wall_side1" name="wall_side1">
            
                        <div style="display: inlineblock;">
                            <label for="wall_side2">Side 2</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="wall_side2" name="wall_side2">
            
                           <img src="https://usabilla.com/graphics/resources/usabilla-logo.png" width="100" height="auto" alt="" >
            
                            <label for="wall_side3">Side 3</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="wall_side3" name="wall_side3">
                        </div>
                        <label for="wall_side4">Side 4</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="wall_side4" name="wall_side4">
                    </div>
                    <label for="ceiling">Ceiling</label>
                        <select name="ceiling" id="ceiling">
                            <option value="1">Yes</option>
                            <option value="0">No</option>
                        </select>
            
                    <label for="tunnels">Tunnels</label>
                    <input type="number" value="0" min="0" max="20" step="1" id="tunnel" name="tunnel">
                    
                    <label for="slides">Slides</label>
                    <input type="number" value="0" min="0" max="20" step="1" id="slide" name="slide">
            
                    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate()">
            
                    <span>Total: $</span>
                    <span id="totalvalue"></span>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="calc.js"></script>
            
                </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```css
div { text-align: center;}
label {margin: 10px ;}
label:first-of-type,
label:last-of-type {display: block;}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Side 1<input type="checkbox" /></label>
  <label>Side 2<input type="checkbox" /></label>
  <img src="https://usabilla.com/graphics/resources/usabilla-logo.png" width="100" height="auto" alt="" >
  <label>Side 3<input type="checkbox" /></label>
  <label>Side 4<input type="checkbox" /></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that's perfects, however could you also center everything inside the form to keep it consistent. That would be very much appreciated but don't let it keep you busy

Comment: Have you tried to do the basic: `<style>form{text-align: center;}</style>` ? seems that it center everything.